# Difference between ways to declare a scope in a directive (ways shown inside)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm new to AngularJS, JavaScript and HTML.

My question is: ¿What is the difference between the four ways to declare the scope in a directive?

I'm going to show the way and then write what I think about it. If i'm wrong or right, tell me in an ordered way please.

This is base in this directive:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: //Here go the 4 ways
  }
});
```

**FIRST WAY:**

```
scope: true
```

What I understand is that:

*A* - A new child scope is created and this child scope inherits from the parent scope that surround it.

*B* - The directive will have access to the parent scope models.

*C* - Is it possible to insert values in this scope. Or is this scope only meant to give access to inherited data?

**SECOND WAY**

```
scope: { // NO content, empty object }
```

*A* - This creates an isolated scope.

*B* - This scope can't access any parent models.

*C* - Although this scope can't access the parent scope, this isolated scope can have child scopes.

**THIRD WAY**

```
//nothing, not declaring scope attribute.
```

**FOURTH WAY**

```
scope: {// SOME content such as data binding strategies}
```

Thanks. Please let this be a place to share information that is related with this very general question (so it actually answers the question), but that also go further based on personal experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you just summarized the different types of creating scopes. 
But you forgot about performance and why creating no isolating scopes can sometimes be better.

**Isolating a scope** will:

- reduce the amount of variables in the different scopes.
- Inheriting from parent scope will cause to clone the watchers, too.
- Prevent you from using multiple directives on one element.

With isolated scopes you **can't** to this:

```
<div myDirective myDirective2></div>
```

This will lead to a **angular exception**.

---

If you are **not isolating** the scope:

- Maybe tons of inherited variables (can be avoided by `scope: false`)
- Can use **multiple directives** at the **same element**

For example `ngModel`,`ngClick`,`ngBlur` ... doesn't isolate the scope, because you can use them on the same element. Like this:

```
<input ng-model="someValue" ng-blur="storeInput()"></input>
```

This wouldn't be possible if they'd isolate their scope.

Comment: Thank you, great answer. So far, the book I'm reading (ng-book) is not caring about optimization, so I did not know about this. This is the kind of answer I'm looking forward to get in this question.